# Can i control height of detail section of Subreport in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, subreport

```
 Dim mainRp As New MainReport
Dim subRp As New SubReportTest

subRp.Section3.Height = 500

 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = mainRp
```

above code not working and not showing any error also

but there is not such thing like

```
mainRp.Subreports("SubReportTest.rpt").Section3.Height = 500
mainRp.Subreports("SubReportTest.rpt").????? 'for set the height of subreport
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ReportDocument class definition, I would say, yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664718(v=vs.71).aspx

Although, I have not tested it before, and beware the units are twips not pixels :)